# Insert data from jsp to database

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp

Which resource have for learning jsp and database.I want insert data from jsp to database(postgres) and i watched video in youtube not work.I did code how that video but not successfully.I take an error :**com.postgres.Driver**, but i have driver.